# In SP 2013 daily email notification with number of items added and deleted in a document librar

Tags: email, notifications

I want to have a daily email notification with number of items added and deleted in a document library which is there in all subsites. How could i do this. Very urgent please some one help me ..

Comment: are you able to write some javascript or c# code?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you help me with this.thank you have a pleasant day ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options to go with is timer job. Which runs on daily basis.

You can include following logic in code:

1. Traverse all sub sites and all the lists.
2. Get the items which are created in last 24 hours and get count of that.
3. Prepare email body content with list name and respective list items.
4. Send email.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.If you don't mind.could you please explain the same in a bit detail way.. which will make me understand it better.

Comment: For example let us consider in all the sub sites we have document library with common name "demo" but different items depends on the sub site. I want to have a daily email saying number of items added in (sub site) X=10 number of items deleted in (sub site) X =20 number of items added in Y=20 so on....

Comment: i would greatly appreciate help on this

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Search Alerts? 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718244.aspx

All you need is a correct search query and two alerts - one for new items and one for deleted items.